# Mermin's EPR paradox explanation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, epr-experiment

I am reading [N. D. Mermin, *Bringing home the atomic world: Quantum mysteries for anybody*](https://physlab.lums.edu.pk/images/e/e3/Reading2-QM2.pdf)
. The main part of the article is pretty clear to me. But I am not sure how quantum mechanics described in Appendix generates Cases (a) and (b) on p.941. Can someone explicate in mathematical details?

Comment: informative of history https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/200511/history.cfm

Comment: Questions must be self-contained. Include the important equations and important quotes in the question (not with images, though!).

Answer (score 2):

I would really help if you just wrote the cases in question out, so we don't have to do all the work.

I did not know the Red/Green box construction was do to David Mermin. His stuff is gold.

Anyway, "C" produces singlet state (up to normalization)

$$ \psi = \psi_{1,2} + \psi_{2,1} = |\uparrow\downarrow\rangle + |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle $$
where the first (second) arrow labels the particles going to detector A (B).

We can write that in matrix form as:
$$ \psi = \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]_1 
\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\end{array}\right]_2 
-
\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\end{array}\right]_1 
\left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\0\end{array}\right]_2 
$$

(Note that the subscripts on the brackets indicate particle index, so these matrices are from different spaces, and don't matrix multiple with each other).

Now $C$ can randomize the angle of the spin quantization, so that state becomes

$$ \psi = \left[\begin{array}{c} \cos(\theta/2)\\\sin(\theta/2)\end{array}\right]_1 \left[\begin{array}{c}\cos((\theta+\pi)/2)\\\sin((\theta+\pi)/2)\end{array}\right]_2 
-
\left[\begin{array}{c}\cos((\theta+\pi)/2)\\\sin((\theta+\pi)/2)\end{array}\right]_1 \left[\begin{array}{c} \cos(\theta/2)\\\sin(\theta/2)\end{array}\right]_2 
$$

where $\theta$ is the angle of quantization wrt to the arbitrary z axis.

Now we set up the switches, which I am not calling $(1,2,3)$ because obv. reasons. They're now $(i, j, k)$, and their alignment directions are (picking a starting angle without loss of generality):

$$  \phi_i = 0 $$
$$ \phi_j = 120^{\circ} $$
$$ \phi_k = 240^{\circ} $$

So if the switches are the same: $A_i=0, B_i=0$ (picking a switch position without loss of generality), and a random state is created. It is measured by detector $A$ (without loss of generality), and choses aligned ($+$) or anti aligned ($-$) with $\phi_i = 0$

Particle $A$ has probabilites

$$p_+ = \cos^2{(\theta-\phi_1)/2} = \cos^2(\theta/2)$$
$$p_- = \sin^2{(\theta-\phi_1)/2} = \sin^2(\theta/2)$$

Note that + (-) means red (green) in A and green (red) in B.

Suppose it is $+$, without loss of generality:

Then $A$ shows red and the state "collapses" (not my favorite term) to:

$$ \psi = \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right] 
\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\end{array}\right]$$

Now when $B$ measures, it see (-) with 100% probability and also shows red.

for different switches, since $\cos^2(\frac{120^{\circ}} 2) = \frac 1 4 $, I'll leave it as an exercise (in MathJax) to show the other case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is $\theta$ distributed uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi)$? How do you describe the R and G configurations and the respective probabilities in terms of your formulation?

Comment: Yes, theta is uniform, but I don't think it has to be. The thing about the singlet spin state is that it invariant under rotations, so maybe that while part was extraneous..I just randomly picked a coordinate system..and physics doesn't care about coordinates.   On Red/Green  I chose: "that + (-) means red (green) in A and green (red) in B".  What I learned from this problem is: you have to do the math in QM, intuition is not a good quantum number. But: the math is linear, so just crank it out.

Comment: From your equation on $p_+$, $\frac{\theta-\phi_1}2=\pm\frac\theta2+k\pi$ which means $\theta=\frac{\phi_1}2+k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbf Z$. For $\phi_1=\frac23m\pi$, $\theta=(\frac23l+k)\pi$ for some $m,l\in \mathbf Z$. Well, I do not quite see how this fits into Mermin's scheme and how the angles and probabilities translate into red and green.

Comment: what are you doing? I'm not solving for phi 1, I'm setting it to zero. then square the amplitude to get the measurement to get the light colors. There is no integer wrapping the phase.